# where to place ssl files .key and .crt in linux

Tags: linux, ssl, apache2

I have to ssl files with extension .key and .crt i have tried to place the file in a location but it unable to access by the virtual host

can you help me with the placing of the file and how to write the path for the file virtual host as well as apache in not getting started !!!

---

Example

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /home/sammy/example.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/sammy/example.com.key
```

Comment: What does "unable to access" mean? Do you get an error message? Does Apache fail to start? Try checking if the files are readable for the Apache user.

Comment: yes the apache fail to start. and how do i check if files are readable by apache use

Comment: A user's home dir is probably not the right place to store cert files, try moving them to `/etc/httpd/conf/` (or where your Apache config files are). Then add read permissions (`chmod go+r example.com.*`). Update references in httpd.conf and restart.